# importin typescript types/interfaces with svelte components triggers compiler error while importing them

Tags: typescript, types, import, svelte, vite

I have a Svelte project that uses Vite as the build tool, and I'm trying to import a TypeScript interface(toDo) in a Svelte component. However, I'm getting an error when I try to compile the component

Here's what my Svelte component looks like:

```
<script type="ts">
   import { toDo } from "./todos.store";
</script>
```

in this code snippet toDo is the type assigned to a toDoItem.

Any ideas on what might be causing this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you add the error message?

Comment: the error is this: 
unexpected token

Comment: Could you add the error message verbatim? Also could you show what your store looks like//

Comment: this is the error: 
```javascript
10:22:49 PM [vite] Internal server error: /src/pages/todos/components/Todo.svelte:2:16 Unexpected token
  Plugin: vite-plugin-svelte
  File: /src/pages/todos/components/Todo.svelte:2:16
   1 |  <script type="ts">
   2 |      import type { toDo } from "../todos.store";
                        ^
   3 |  
   4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `type='ts'` to `lang='ts'`, and if you're importing a type it's good practice to specify that such like:

```
import type { toDo } from "./todos.store";
```

Comment: thank you. this helpped with the issue.

Comment: You actually have to import with `type`, at least previously that has been the case.

Comment: @H.B. please explain your comment. i am new to svelte.

Comment: @mishoo78: It had something to do with the preprocessing removing such imports erroneously cause problems with the compilation. Could be different by now.